# How to paste text starting with a quote (') without weird behaviour

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to copy and paste text from a cell. I want the cell to read `+ events`. I need to add a quote so that it's not interpreted as an incorrect formula, so the cell is `'+ events` and reads `+ events`.

But when I copy and paste the text `'+ eventsCmd`, the single quote `'` is not masked, so the cell is `'+ events` but still reads `'+ events`.

- Why does it behave like that, and what can I do about it? I could copy the cells itself but I would also paste formatting and it's not much better.
- If I can paste text without it being formatted, why can't I paste `+ events` without Excel adding an `=` before it?

[image: Minimal example]

Here's a screenshot, the second cell has the same content as the first one but the `'` is not masked. This happens when I paste the text directly on the cell, not if I paste it in the top bar (but that takes twice as many time).

---

I'm using Excel 2013 from the Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 suite.

Comment: Where are you copying the text from?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad from one cell, to another

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1413332/edit) to include the version of Excel you are using and maybe a screen cap of the problem cell and the formula bar for it?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I added a screenshot and clarification about how to reproduce it. It doesn't happen if I paste it on the formula bar, but I don't understand why (and it's about twice as long)

Comment: I don't have this problem in Excel 2007 12.0.4518.1014. I type `'+ events` in A1, enter, arrow up, ctrl+c, down arrow, ctrl+v; A2 contains `'+ events` and both show `+ events`

Comment: @AlexM If you do arrow up, ctrl+c, you copy the cell, with all its formatting. I have different colors on every row so it's a problem

Comment: @phuclv Well I guess I have a weird version of excel with my weird version of windows (it's probably off-topic but windows also has weird behaviours compared to my personnal windows). For example, I can't triple-click on the formula bar to select all, I HAVE to select all the text with my mouse manually, I don't think that's normal.

Comment: I can reproduce in office 365 if I double click in the cell and highlight the contents, then copy and paste, or if I highlight the contents of the top bar.  I can avoid by not highlighting the contents and just using copy and paste with ctrl+c or ctrl+v.

Comment: To reproduce this problem you should copy the text (the content of the cell), not the cell itself, it also works if you copy the text from an application other than Excel. The change from `'+` to `+` will be made when the cell is validated (double click or edit the cell then press Enter).

Comment: I managed to reproduce it both in 2013 and 2016. @Teleporting Goat -- If you copy the cell and do a paste special "Values" you should be able to keep the destination cell's format

Comment: @Stormweaker I think that's it. If you paste text directly **on** a cell, without double clicking it or the formula bar, the content is never validated, so the quote is not masked. That explains why it disappears if I edit, make no change and press Enter. (Though if you just paste `+ events` it WILL try to validate and display `#NAME?`)

Comment: it was late at night at my place, so I've actually reproduced your problem but didn't even realized it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick F2 before Ctrl+V will avoid the behaviour you're describing.

[image: Example below.]

Answer (score 2):

The characters `=`, `+` and `-` are used to start a formula, if you do not want to have this behavior and are bothered by the use of `'`, you can format cells as Text to prevent Excel from creating a formula.

(Sorry, image is in French)

[image]